# Get Session From Php To Codeigniter SSO?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap, single-sign-on

I'm a newbie of codeigniter. On php i have an single sign-on to another web, but at codeigniter i want to give the session from php to codeigniter. Someone can give me advice to get the session from php?

Comment: _"but at codeigniter i want to give the session from php to codeigniter"_ - Codeigniter _is_ PHP. It's a PHP framework. You really need to edit your question. It's _very_ unclear...

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after login success set the login details to session and check those session variable on any variable, like 
$this->session->userdata('your variable name');

do this in your controller under login function,
need help then please let me know, happy to help. :)

```
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['pwd'];

  $login_chk = $this->mainModel->login_chk($email,$password); // mainmodel is my model name which consist od login_chk function.

         $data=array(
                'username' => $login_chk['name'],
                'is_logged' => TRUE
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data); // this is how i am seeting session.
```